# Change SCCM 2012 PXE Boot.wim to a new Boot.wim

Tags: pxe-boot, sccm-2012

I have created a new boot.wim file for our SCCM 2012 install.  We currently use PXE to image machines so I would like to make the new boot.wim the new PXE image.  I have imported the boot.wim into SCCM and marked it for use with PXE.  I have also distributed it to the distribution points that have PXE on them.  I went in and made sure the properties matched the old one and unchecked PXE from the old boot.wim.

The issue is that it is still looking for the old boot.wim file and I cannot figure out how to point it to the new one.  The new boot.wim is just the old one with some added drivers. (I couldn't get them to load the traditional way with SCCM.  I am sure there is some issue, but I need this to work sooner than later)

The log file shows this:

```
Looking for bootImage BM10009E  SMSPXE  5/25/2017 10:02:23 AM   3512 (0x0DB8)
C8:5B:76:EB:EF:E1, 9312B8CC-26C3-11B2-A85C-E0E9050C3398: could not find boot image BM10009E SMSPXE  5/25/2017 10:02:23 AM   3512 (0x0DB8)
C8:5B:76:EB:EF:E1, 9312B8CC-26C3-11B2-A85C-E0E9050C3398: Not serviced.  SMSPXE  5/25/2017 10:02:23 AM   3512 (0x0DB8)

BM10009E is the old boot.wim 

Looking further up the log file I do see where it is trying to load the new one but there are a lot of errors:

Found new image BM10013E    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:28 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Loaded Windows Imaging API DLL (version '10.0.10586.0') from location 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\wimgapi.dll'    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:30 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Opening image file G:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\BM10013E\boot.BM10013E.wim    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:30 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Found Image file: G:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\BM10013E\boot.BM10013E.wim
 PackageID: BM10013E
 ProductName: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
 Architecture: 9
 Description: Microsoft Windows PE (x64)
 Version:  
 Creator: 
 SystemDir: WINDOWS
    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:30 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Closing image file G:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\BM10013E\boot.BM10013E.wim    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:30 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\PXE\wdsnbp.com'. Error code: 0x80004005 SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\x86\wdsnbp.com'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\PXE\abortpxe.com'. Error code: 0x80004005   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\x86\abortpxe.com'. Error code: 0x80004005  SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:43 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:44 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:44 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\PXE\pxeboot.com'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:44 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:44 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:44 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\x64\pxeboot.com'. Error code: 0x80004005   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:44 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:45 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:45 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\PXE\pxeboot.n12'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:45 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:45 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:45 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\x64\pxeboot.n12'. Error code: 0x80004005   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:45 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:46 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:46 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\PXE\wdsnbp.com'. Error code: 0x80004005 SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:46 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:46 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:46 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\x64\wdsnbp.com'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:46 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:47 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:47 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\PXE\abortpxe.com'. Error code: 0x80004005   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:47 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:47 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:47 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\x64\abortpxe.com'. Error code: 0x80004005  SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:47 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\Fonts\segmono_boot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005 SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\Fonts\segmono_boot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\Fonts\segoe_slboot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005 SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:48 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\Fonts\segoe_slboot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\Fonts\segoen_slboot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\Fonts\segoen_slboot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTempBootFiles\BM10013E\WINDOWS\Boot\Fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Invalid file version '' found   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
CcmGetFileVersion failed with 0x80004005    SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
Failed to retrieve the version of file 'G:\RemoteInstall\SMSBoot\Fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf'. Error code: 0x80004005   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:55:49 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
File G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2017.05.25.09.05.36.18.{C167C29B-D4B4-4B7D-9B16-74D823FA20CC}.boot.bcd deleted.   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:56:26 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
File G:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2017.05.25.09.05.36.18.{C167C29B-D4B4-4B7D-9B16-74D823FA20CC}.boot.bcd.log deleted.   SMSPXE  5/25/2017 9:56:26 AM    3584 (0x0E00)
```

I appreciate the help.  I really need this to work so we can start deploying the new machines we just got.

Answer (score 0):

SCCM uses the boot WIM from the last advertised Task Sequence as the default. I've gotten around this in the past by deleting the advertisement for the task sequence using the new boot WIM & then re-advertising it to whichever collection it was deployed to originally. It should then use that WIM as the default boot WIM. This is default behaviour for SCCM.

Hope that helps.